# Connecting older network to existing local area network

Tags: networking, network-share, wifi

I'm attempting to connect two networks right now. The first is a peer to peer containing two systems, one running Windows XP and the other is a CNC router running IBM's OS/2 Warp. This is an older network, I currently need the Windows XP to be able to view the CNC's file server and put operations on the CNC router. I have a second network consisting of 4 Windows 10 computers and a few other systems such as a printer. My goal is to remove the Windows XP computer for various reasons and have the Windows 10 computers connect to the CNC router.

I've tried connecting all of the systems to the same network through ethernet cables, the Windows XP computer can successfully ping the Windows 10 computers however, the Windows XP computer and CNC router do not show up on the network.

Comment: What is the IP addressing of all the devices? Do they all have exactly the same subnet mask? What do you mean by _"do not show up on the network"_?